# TV Shows for Web Master and Design Firms

Tags: learning, education

Are there existing TV Shows we're they talk about the Web Industry? (Web Mastering, Web Designing, Web Developing, Interviews and Tips and Tricks).

TV shows can be interesting for us, It can be a good source of inspiration. Information from TV shows can be delivered to your audience fast and would be good for people who don't like to read much. Topic I'm interested to watch are Successful Stories of Design Firms and Their Workflow. Another is some sneak peak on their Company and WorkStation (similar to MTV Cribs) lol.

I'm open to Internet Channels (Youtube, Adobe TV).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one site worth a look called 5by5. http://5by5.tv/

You would be interested in the big web show. http://5by5.tv/bigwebshow

"Hosted by Dan Benjamin and Jeffrey Zeldman.

The Big Web Show features special guests and topics like web publishing, art direction, content strategy, typography, web technology, and more. It's everything web that matters."

There a several others out there, I would check iTunes Podcasts.

Also, there is a film coming out Life in Perpetual Beta http://lifeinperpetualbeta.com/

Comment: wow awesome find :) I hate to close this thread, But this already answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

I've thought about creating one, but I haven't seen any out in the wild. Of course, there are countless video tutorials, screencasts, and conference speeches out there. Check out [YUI Theater](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/) for a sampling.

Comment: If you haven't seen any, and you like the topic so much, that you thought about creating one - I'd say go for it! Maybe together with some people from webmasters.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow and serverfault. Could be great!

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement, Chris. There are a few other things that need to come first for us, but it's definitely on the radar as a possibility for the future.

Comment: @chris_l yeah same thought here. I'll be happy to support this idea :)